# Positioning image on top of background

Tags: html, css

I would like to position image to be on top of that background, and I did it but partially...

[JSfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/y8y6defa/)

```
.home-main{
      background-color: #d2dfff;
      height: 150px;
      margin-bottom: 50px;
      margin-top: 50px;
      position: relative;}
```

If I add `margin-top:100px;` it will move down, and I just want background to move so the image is a bit over and under that "blue" background.

Also how to position that text to be on the right of that image, I tried with `float:left` but I am missing something...

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Best regards,

Comment: Just remove the .home-text selector you have http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/y8y6defa/1/. But I don't know what you mean by _"the image is a bit over and under that "blue" background."_

Comment: There are many ways to achieve the result you want, negative margin is one of them. http://jsfiddle.net/y8y6defa/2/

Comment: @j08691 thanks but Nick and Kelv.Gonzales got it right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help from the comments above, I have used the negative margin and taken out the `float:left` from your `.home-text` so it utilizes its inline properties to go to the right of the img div.

[Here are the results](http://jsfiddle.net/y8y6defa/4/)